# Insert form data in excel sheet by adding a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have very basic VBA skills and hope you can help me out. 
I am trying to insert values from a user excel form on a sheet, when a user clicks on 'add record' button. I have named few cells in my sheet as cities, based on which I want to first add an empty column after that particular city get selected from my combo (cboCities) and then insert values of my three text boxes in that column.

```
    Private Sub cmdbtnSave_Click()
Dim vNewCol As Long
Worksheets("DataEntry").Range(Me.cboCities.value).EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert

   vNewCol = Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(Columns.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Column
    ' Input the data
    If Me.cboCities.value <> "" Then
       Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(7, vNewCol).value = Me.Indic.value
       Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(11, vNewCol).value = Me.Option1.value
    End If

End Sub
```

The problems is, how do i know the 'number' or 'reference' of that column which got inserted above and then enter values of text boxes? In the below code, instead of hard coded "P", I need some dynamic way to know the ID or reference of that new column which was inserted above.

```
 vNewCol = Worksheets("DataEntry").Cells(Columns.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Column
```

Thank you for guiding me.

Comment: Can you do this by replacing `"P"` with `ActiveCell.EntireColumn`?

Comment: it gives me an error of 'Type mismatch' when I replace the "P" with ActiveCell.EntireColumn

Comment: Sorry, try `vNewCol = Worksheets("DataEntry").ActiveCell.EntireColumn` that will give you a reference to the column of the currently active cell

Comment: This time the error is different, "Object doesn't support that property or method"

Comment: How about `Worksheets("DataEntry").Activate`, then `vNewCol = ActiveCell.Column`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to know this?

```
vNewCol=Worksheets("DataEntry").Range(Me.cboCities.value).Offset(0, 1).Column
```